# Unity Number Wizard Back Button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I just created a Number Game witch guesses what number you are thinking of and shows it to the screen as a TextMeshProUGUI element. I want to add a back button so that when you press the incorrect button the TextMeshProUGUI element displays the value that was displayed before the user pressed the incorrect button.

Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class NumberWizard : MonoBehaviour {

[SerializeField] SceneLoader sceneLoader;
[SerializeField] int max;
[SerializeField] int min;
[SerializeField] TextMeshProUGUI guessText;

int guess;

// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    StartGame();
}

void StartGame()
{
    NextGuess();
}

public void OnPressHigher()
{
    min = guess + 1;
    NextGuess();
}

public void OnPressLower()
{
    max = guess - 1;
    NextGuess();
}

void NextGuess()
{
    guess = Random.Range(min, max+1);
    guessText.text = guess.ToString();
}

public void Back()
{
    //Back code should go here
}
}
```

[Scene View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fayHB.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just have to remember the last guess:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class NumberWizard : MonoBehaviour {

[SerializeField] SceneLoader sceneLoader;
[SerializeField] int max;
[SerializeField] int min;
[SerializeField] TextMeshProUGUI guessText;

int guess;
int lastGuess;
int lastMin;
int lastMax;

// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    StartGame();
}

void StartGame()
{
    NextGuess();
}

public void OnPressHigher()
{
    lastMin = min;

    min = guess + 1;
    NextGuess();
}

public void OnPressLower()
{
    lastMax = max;

    max = guess - 1;
    NextGuess();
}

void NextGuess()
{
    lastGuess = guess;

    guess = Random.Range(min, max+1);
    guessText.text = guess.ToString();
}

public void Back()
{
    guess = lastGuess;
    min = lastMin;
    max = lastMax;

    guessText.text = guess.ToString();
}
}
```

if this is not what you want, please write a comment and i will edit the answer

Comment: I tried that but for some reason when i click something like higher, higher, back, lower it displays a higher number, but is supposed to display a lower number.